# Print on client's printer

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I am developing web application in Java, and I must print reports, when clicked on button, on client side printer. How to implement? How to show printers from client side???

I use:

```
PrintService[] printers =
PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

But this is on server side.

Comment: If you need to print on client side then you need to use `javascript window.print()` method.

Comment: I develop in Java,and I must print some report @androidGenX

Comment: hey if my answer is correct make it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

As your requirement is not clear. I am not sure about what exactly you want  but for print you can use this `window.print()`

```js
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

```html
<p>Click To print.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)(simple) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121)(explained).

**Edit:**
And if you want to print a particulate element content you can use this function:

```
 function myPrint(data) 
{
    var testPage = window.open('', 'Test Page',  'height=500,width=500');
    testPage.document.write('<html><head><title>Test Page</title>');
    testPage.document.write('</head><body >');
    testPage.document.write(data);
    testPage.document.write('</body></html>');
    testPage.document.close(); 
    testPage.focus(); 
    testPage.print();
    testPage.close();
    return ;
}
```

Comment: I develop in Java,and I must print some report @Anand Singh

Comment: is your report in some html element?

Comment: I compile and fill jasper reports,and I must print! Sorry,my English is not good! @Anand Singh

Comment: Edited, You can use this(myPrint) function and provide a print functionality in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You must use javascript on the client page.

```
window.print()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

If you want to try the applet approach give a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440687/guide-on-creating-a-java-applet-printing-without-prompt)

> You cannot do that for security reasons. If you could, applets would
>   already have become notorious for printing 10+ pages of 'special
>   offers' when you visit unscrupulous web sites.
>
> OTOH, if the client is willing to accept one prompt at applet
>   start-up, you could digitally sign the code.

Also it should be possible to achieve a similar result using the PrintService from [JNLP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html) without the need for a signed applet.

Like in the Following example

```
import javax.jnlp.*; 
    ... 

    PrintService ps; 

    try { 
        ps = (PrintService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.PrintService"); 
    } catch (UnavailableServiceException e) { 
        ps = null; 
    } 

    if (ps != null) { 
        try { 

            // get the default PageFormat
            PageFormat pf = ps.getDefaultPage(); 

            // ask the user to customize the PageFormat
            PageFormat newPf = ps.showPageFormatDialog(pf); 

            // print the document with the PageFormat above
            ps.print(new DocToPrint()); 

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    // Code to construct the Printable Document
    class DocToPrint implements Printable {
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageformat, int PageIndex){
            // code to generate what you want to print   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I develop in Java,and I must print some report @Bolza

Comment: You do realize you cannot force an action on the user's printer from the server, do you? You need to do it client side.

Comment: I understand! I think using applet,be solved my problem or javascript?@Bolza

Comment: Guys most browsers have blocked applet support.

Comment: @ Landre if you got the solution please feel free to share it